# Does "stacked switch with two separate legs, one 3-way and one dimmer" electrical part exist?

Tags: electrical

I have a very old house built from adobe. I have a workman trying to make a connection for a chandelier where there was previously no connection and he says he needs something to do this that he thinks doesn't exist. I told him to tell me and I'd search the internet. He says he needs a

> stacked switch with two separate switch legs, one 3-way and one dimmer

so it's out to you experts to tell me if this exists?

Comment: This is bordering on "shop for me"..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a double 3 way it will work [single gang double 3 way](http://www.westsidewholesale.com/leviton-5243-w.html?keyword=Google_Shopping&gclid=COi-sOzP_MsCFVBhfgod100K7w) it will work for your needs except the dimmer. One switch used for 3 way and only 1/2 of the 2nd switch is used for on off. Ok dimmer it gets a bit more expensive as you will need this style [retro double digital](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0017O2V0A) you will also need a second switch single gang that can talk to this one similar to this [single dimmer](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/9900953234900853036/reviews?q=Lutron+Maestro+MA-R-WH+Dimmer,+White&oq=Lutron+Maestro+MA-R-WH+Dimmer,+White&ie=UTF-8&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j69i61.2178j0j4&sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.118817766,d.cGc&biw=1920&bih=979&dpr=1&tch=1&ech=1&psi=vGMGV9jjOo7UjwPgsoeoCg.1460036504559.3&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqm_770_zLAhVQzWMKHeVZC3YQvCQIvQE). I have not used a double with a single in the past so double check that the single wont affect both on the double.